# Procedure in derived class doesn't return derived object

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class

I have a base class in C# like:

```
public class A{
  public A something() {
     //...
  }
}
```

And a derived class like:

```
public class B:A
```

When I do:

```
B obj = new B();
obj = obj.something();
```

VS throws an error saying (something like) "A can't be converted to B". Isn't it supposed to return B and not A?

**Update:**
Thank you all.

I've changed A.something(string) and now is A.something(int). The values passed to it are always ints, so... B (and other "sister" classes) are just a midstep in a full refactoring of the code, so they will disappear.

The case is that I have 4 classes that do the same and I'm changing'em for a unified one. Thus the need to return "B" objects for now.

Comment: because your function something() return type is `A` and you can not hold your parent members in child but otherway(Parent reference variable can point to child class instance) is possible.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to implement the factory method pattern, check this out: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, even though it's defined in the base class, the return type won't be different, it will still return an instance of `A` which is not necessarily convertible to B. You could do something like this:

```
public class A{
  public virtual A something() {
     //...
  }
}

public class B:A
{
   public override A something() {
     return new B();
   }
}

B obj = new B();
obj = obj.something() as B;
```

Of course, the override does not really solve anything here. You could just return a `B` in the base class and it would work the same way, but that's just awkward.
I think your issue is that you are not following the LISKOV substitution principle here: you should be able to replace every instance of `A` with an instance that implements `A` without affecting the client. Downcasting in general is a code smell. You should treat all instances as `A`'s and vary the behavior in your subclasses, not in the clients

Comment: i think `overrides` shouldbe `override` mightbe a typo :)

Comment: I'm refactoring the classes in a project at work and it's such a mess that I have to do some weird compromises (imagine a class that has 20something vars and a name() that returns the name... by hand. Or a switch-case with a return "" outside it so "the compiler doesn't throw an error". This is in the code too).

The final code should be cleaner but this solution is a provisional one).

Answer (score 0):

> VS throws an error saying (something like) "A can't be converted to
>   B". Isn't it supposed to return B and not A?

because your parent class function `something()` return type is `A`, and you are trying save that in Child class reference variable `obj` as below:

```
obj = obj.something(); //something returns instance of `A`
```

here child class reference variable `obj` can not point to  parent class instance but otherway(Parent class reference variable can point to child class instance) is possible.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider changing the return type of the `something()` method in A class.

- it should return void
- you can pass a parameter via reference if you need to modify it in the function

This way you can overload/override the method in the derived class to get a different behavior if you need to.

the way it looks now there is not much you can do except a reinterpret_cast  which will cause problems later on.

Answer (score -2):

Either you have to override Something() in Class B or get result of obj.something(); in Class A's Object.

Comment: Overriding doesn't solve his problem. The return type is still `A`